# RecyclerView image from Firebase fails to load for one activity out of three

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I have a MainActivity that calls 3 activities -

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_main);

    CardView c1 = findViewById(R.id.card1);
    c1.setOnClickListener(view -> startActivity(new Intent(this, QuoteActivity.class)));

    CardView c2 = findViewById(R.id.card2);
    c2.setOnClickListener(view -> startActivity(new Intent(this, ReadingActivity.class)));

    CardView c3 = findViewById(R.id.card3);
    c3.setOnClickListener(view -> startActivity(new Intent(this,MotivationActivity.class)));
```

.....

All the 3 activities use RecyclerView.Adapter to load images and text from Firebase storage.
Problem is arbitrarily image loading fails for one of the 3 activities with the below error -

I/FIAM.Display: Binding to activity: FirebaseLibrary.ReadingActivity
I/FIAM.Headless: Setting display event component
W/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service

Which activity will not work is absolutely random. If I remove one activity, one fails out of the remaining 2. With Breakpoint, I can see that it is not entering onDataChange -

private void GetDataFromFirebase() {

```
    Query query = myref.child("quote");
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ClearAll();
            ArrayList<Messages> randommessagesList = new ArrayList<>();
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Messages messages = new Messages();

                messages.setImageUrl(Objects.requireNonNull(snapshot1.child("image").getValue()).toString());
                messages.setName(Objects.requireNonNull(snapshot1.child("name").getValue()).toString());

                messagesList.add(messages);
            }
            int messagesCount = messagesList.size();
            int randomNumber = new Random().nextInt(messagesCount);

            randommessagesList.add(messagesList.get(randomNumber));

            recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), randommessagesList);
            quoterecyclerview.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
            recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

Any help what might be going wrong?

Resolved :
As I expected the issue was with the New App Checker in Firebase that is still Beta. Firebase access was fine with Playstore published App but was having issue while installing via Android Studio for testing. Just removed the App checked initialization for testing ...

Comment: Your worries are about "No adapter attached; skipping layout"?

Comment: Yes exactly. No idea why it happens randomly for one activity out of 3.

Comment: You shouldn't set the adapter in a background thread. Please check the duplicate tp see how you can solve this.

Comment: You are right. If I do so, I don't see the error but the page is blank. I really don't suspect the code in the activity as it works. I have replicated the same code into 3 activities. Problem is in every execution it works for only 2 activities randomly. For the other one execution does not even enter onDataChange.

Comment: OnDataChange Method runs on the main thread. maybe the problem is above that query fire

Answer (score 0):

```
W/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

Maybe This line is showing an issue. Are you sure that you have set the recycler view adapter properly?

Comment: Yes. Because all of the 3 activities work in few execution. So, in one execution just 2 of them work, randomly. No idea why just one (Anyone of the 3) does not work.

Comment: can you add some more code please

Comment: Thanks .... can you be a little more specific on which part of the code will help?

Comment: Does this code block runs when you debug app?

Comment: No. Flow is not entering "onDataChange".

Comment: app is crashing somewhere or just data is not appearing in RV

Comment: There is No crash at all. Today I changed all the 3 activities to Fragments but the issue is same. One of them just does not work...

Comment: I think your code not reaching a query at all.  before query fire, something might happens